# composer: command not found in phpseclib SSH2

Tags: php, ssh, server, phpseclib, ssh2

I have connected with my server using `phpseclib` and I want to run 3 commands in a particular folder but I am facing several issues in this library.
**1** I am getting 
`stdin: is not a tty bash:` 
error after every command.I did google and found a solution to add
 `$ssh->enablePTY();` then i am not able to see my output its returning 1 or 0.
**2** After adding $ssh->enablePTY(); when i am trying to run another command i am facing

```
If you want to run multiple exec()'s you will need to disable (and re-enable if appropriate) a PTY for each one
```

So i have added `$ssh->enablePTY();` and `$ssh->disablePTY();` before and after of every command then i can see only 1 and 0 not output of my command.

**3** I want to run 3 commands back to back in a particular folder so executed

```
echo $ssh->exec('cd /home/my/public_html/testmags/; composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition /home/my/public_html/testmags/');
```

but I am facing `composer: command not found`.
I have spent 2 days on this but unable to solve any of these problems.
Small help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: To run composer on that other server, have you checked whether it is installed after all? If yes, have you checked whether it is present in the given folder?

Comment: I have connected with my sever using PUTTY .Composer command is working there but using this lib its not shwoing there.

Answer (score 0):

For PTY's you need to do `$ssh->read()` after `$ssh->exec()`. The reason being that PTY's enable interactivity. eg.

```
$ssh->enablePTY();
$ssh->exec('passwd');
echo $ssh->read('password:');
$ssh->write("badpw\n");
echo $ssh->read('password unchanged');
```

One thing you could do, incidentally, depending on your commands, is to chain them. eg. `$ssh->exec('cmd1; cmd2; cmd3');` or `$ssh->exec('cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3');`.

> but I am facing `composer: command not found`

Do you have composer installed? What does `$ssh->exec('echo $PATH'); echo $ssh->read();` say? Does it include the path where Composer is (globally) installed (if it is indeed installed?). Per https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally if it is globally installed it'll probably live at `/usr/local/bin/`